# Unable to execute git hook

Tags: git, githooks, gitolite

I'm using Gitolite and Redmine together. I created a bare repo (`contacts`) with RW+ permissions for the user `user`, Gitolite is running under user `git` and Redmine under `redmine`. To use Redmine I cloned `contacts` with the command `git clone --mirror` in the same machine and configured Redmine.

I commit and push with `user` and created a `post-receive` hook in the bare repo to fetch the changes (`git remote update`) in the local repo.

The problem is that the hook is never executed and I need to do it manually to update it, but when I try, I get the error `error: cannot open FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied` even when `user` is part of `git` group.

How to make sure the hook is working?

Answer (score 0):

> I commit and push with `user`

You can commit with '`user`' or any other account.

But if you push to a gitolite repo, you are always pushing (using the ssh url) as git. Check your remote origin url (`git remote -v`, or with a recent git, `git remote get-url origin`). It should be git@/yourRepo.

If not, you are [bypassing gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#ybpfail), which is problematic.